# Python: Connect disconnected graph segments with minimal cost

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Consider a graph where we have multiple segments which are disconnected between each other. I would like to find where I need to add new edges to make the graph fully connected. I'd like to keep the length of each new edge to the minimum. Bonus if the algorithm also returns the length of each edge to be added.

---

Existing graph

[image: Existing graph]

---

Proposed solution

[image: Proposed solution]

Comment: Are you sure that you want the graph to be fully connected and not just connected?

Comment: Sounds like 3 conceptual steps: 1. detect what the connected components are (this is O(v)), 2. find the shortest path between each pair of connected components (obvious solution is O(n*m) where n and m are the number of vertices in the subgraphs, but can be near linear using a location-based map), 3. use Prim's algorithm to generate a minimum spanning tree (treating each connected component as a node) - this is basically linear if you choose the data structures right.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by making the edges short.  This suggests there's an underlying geometry you haven't mentioned.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a sample network?

Comment: 1. Sorry, it should be just connected, not fully connected.
2. By making edges short, I mean that I want connect segments at narrowest gaps betwen them.
3. I have tried networkx where I iterate over GeoJSON LineStrings and create a graph from them. It results in multiple `connected_components`.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a method that is slightly similar to the one mentioned by @o11c, 
1. Detect all the components in the graph this can be achieved in linear time O(V+E) by using just doing a simple BFS/DFS. 
2. By `narrowest gaps between them` I'm assuming that you want the smallest length(distance) edge between the two vertices belonging to the different components.  If say that each of the vertex is a point on a plane,  then we could [find the closest points(Vertices)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) where the vertices belong in two components & connect them

Comment: @MohammedMeraj How would you go about finding the closest point in a different component? Would that simply be iterating over all points in the order of ascending distance, checking if the point belong to a different component and returning if it does?

Comment: @shadesofdarkred yes we would sort the distance in ascending order and check if the pair that constitutes a closest pair, happen to belong to 2 different components would have to connected